# increase idle_timeout for database connection in a sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sidekiq

I have a sidekiq worker which takes more than few hours to download and parse a file.
During that time I get the error

> terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout

How to increase the idle_timeout in a sidekiq worker?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL doesn't have an `idle_timeout`.  Maybe that is a sidekiq-internal thing.  But based on the precise wording of the error message, I would say that what you probably need to change is PostgreSQL's `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`.  There are many ways to set PostgreSQL settings (as described in the docs).  But since this defaults to 0 (inactive), I would ask how did it get set in the first place?

Put it does seem like it would be better to parse the file outside of the transaction.